# google app engine determine if code running on traffic allocated instance

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm trying to determine if Java8 Servlet code is running on a traffic-allocated instance on Google App Engine. I cannot seem to find an environment variable or anything that would provide that information. I'm searching for this answer for a Standard (not flex) instance.

I've looked [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/accessing-instance-metadata). 
I've also tried this code, but it returns "Production" whether running on a traffic-allocated instance or not:

```
SystemProperty.environment.value()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by traffic allocated (or not)?

Comment: There is the option to allocate traffic to an instance on the console under App Engine ->Versions:

[link] (https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions?organizationId=123...4786&project=project_name)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an environment variable that provides the information you're looking for. Environment variables are used for configuration purposes such as knowing the IP of a SQL instance or changing code-paths between production and development, but they cannot tell you about the current state of the running instances.

Google App Engine offers the option of configuring [liveness and readiness](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/how-instances-are-managed) health checks. The first periodically sends an HTTP request to a given endpoint to check responsiveness, the second is aimed to know if a just started instance is prepared to accept incoming requests. They're both configured through the [app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml#updated_health_checks) file.

With that being said, you could manually check your application by making an HTTP request and confirm you get a 200 OK code in response. Be aware that some endpoints could work while others could make your app to crash so I recommend you to test all the code-paths to be sure the app as a whole is rock solid.

---

Edit: Added information on how to check if the instance has traffic allocated.

In the Instances tab of App Engine you can see the requests attended by each of your app instances as well as their InstanceId. Then you could further check your instances through the Logs Viewer tab of Stackdriver Logging given that every connection has been logged. You can specify a particular instance filtering the logs with the tag `protoPayload.instanceId:<YOUR-INSTANCE-ID>`. The presence of logs in a given timeframe indicates the that the instance was receiving and attending requests so it is traffic allocated.

Comment: Thanks for the info on liveness and readiness. Thanks also for your comments on getting 200 back, I understand what you mean there. However, it doesn't quite give the answer I was looking for. 

That is, within a running instance, is there any way to determine if it's an instance with traffic allocation. I'm guessing that I could use a query against the production domain name, catch that query and reply with the instance name, which if only a single instance were running might provide the info requested.

Comment: @user12633319 Glad to hear the information was useful and excuse me for the misunderstanding. I have updated my answer to include the information you asked for. Let me know if I can be of further help.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't a programmatic solution, therefore, it's not solving the core issue. I think the approach of using the Http approach works except when traffic splitting, which isn't the typical configuration.